# What is the easiest way to attach sata cables to the backplane of a 1U super micro case?

Tags: cable, cable-management

It seems that the raid controller breakout cable thats designed for the backplane makes its incredibly difficult to cable it. The right angle bend sata cables need to bend down, making it very difficult to attach them.

Is there an easier way? Should I remove the backplane, cable it then reinstall?

Thanks

Comment: Why not purchase some straight SATA cables?

Comment: @joeqwerty
Because its a break out adapter from the raid card. I have a straight cable variant, but then it hits the fans.

Comment: Not all of the fan enclosures house fans.  Consider routing through the ones that don't.  Honestly, I've never had a problem cabling these (and I've done a ton); can you post a picture of the cable you're using and how you're routing it?

Comment: I concur with @BMDan - a photo speaks a thousand words in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found was to remove the fan array and airflow blocking styrofoam by pulling the clip release on the top end of the fan array. Some of the older models have the fan array held in by rubber nipples that mate with metal pins. In this case removing the fan array is just lifting up.

Note. Even with the fan and styrofoam removed, port 3 can be a little tricky. Needle nose pliers can really help.